# Saving multiple printed values output to csv

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, csv, beautifulsoup

How can I save the multiple printed output to the csv? Thanks!

```
page_html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, 'lxml')

names = soup.findAll('a', {"class": "a3H7pd r29r0b shntl"})
links = soup.findAll('a', {"class": "a3H7pd r29r0b shntl"})

for index, name in enumerate(names):
    r = name.get_text(), "https://www.google.com" + links[index]['href']
    print(r)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'column_name' : [0] * len(names) }
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['column_name'])

for index, name in enumerate(names):
  r = name.get_text(), "https://www.google.com" + links[index]['href']
  df.loc[index, 'column_name'] = r

df.to_csv('your_file_path_and_name.csv')
```

Or more concise :

```
list = [name.get_text(), "https://www.google.com" + links[index]['href'] for index, name in enumerate(names)]
df = pd.DataFrame(list, columns = ['column_name'])
df.to_csv('your_file_path_and_name.csv')
```